# Are there pre-printed wall images that might engender understanding in a very young child?

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy

I just read Moebius Noodles. (Thanks for the recommendation Sue). Part of the book talks about keeping images about math around the house.

My child's 18 months. But I figure, why not now. It's passive; so if it helps now, it helps now. If it doesn't, maybe it will help later.

I've been looking for images available as decals or posters that illustrate important concepts. Unfortunately, after searching, I've only found posters about numerals and 'sacred geometry' (admittedly, cool looking - but Metatron's Cube doesn't seem to illustrate anything didactive.).

What kind of images should I be looking for?
Do they exist? What kind of keywords can I used to find them?

Comment: What examples of "images about math" does the book give?

Comment: There's one about exponents and fractals. I can imagine several helpful ones myself as well. However, I can't find anything pre-printed. Maybe I'm not using the right terms. I assume the products are out there. (Edited the question to clarify. Thank you.)

Comment: I'm neither a developmental psychologist nor a parent (nor I have I read the book), but I suspect that anything that sparks curiosity and creates conversations about the relationship between elements is mathematical at some important level.  Escher is a formal artist who was working in that venue quite a bit.  But it could be as simplistic as a Venn diagram made up of red, yellow, and blue circles whose intersections were orange, green, purple, and brown.  The key points would be inviting that curiosity and developing the vocabulary to facilitate that conversation.

Comment: I would say that with the modern computers color drawing became pretty easy (and I don't think you need to be super-good in your painting skills to produce something a small child will appreciate), so the question for me seems more like "what to draw?" rather than where to get the ready images. I should confess however that I tried to hang various math pictures around the house when my daughter was small (mostly of my own creation) and she still went into arts and humanities when she grew up to my utter disappointment though her math exam scores have been always pretty good...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you for the reference, Sue! This was one of the too-quick recommendations in "Moebius Noodles" that may not make sense without context, and we need to add some in the next edition. Meanwhile...

Why put up visible math around the house?

**Value affirmation.** Some things are around for their utility, like the kitchen sink. If a portrait is up, though, that's because we value that person in our lives. We make some math visible in our space to affirm that we value it. You can invite your toddler to browse something like http://gallery.bridgesmathart.org/exhibitions/2022-joint-mathematics-meetings (love their galleries!) and print out whatever the kid pokes, to start. Grown-ups can put up math that makes them emotional in some way, that connects to their lives, even a little, that evokes a memory, etc. Feelings are shareable with young kids, even if they don't understand the math!

One of the examples I have up right now:

[image: Art Forms in Nature]

I do a lot of nature scavenger hunts with kids, and Haeckel is a great source for growing our math eyes.

**Invitation to play.** A picture plus some "manipulatives" at the child's eye level is an awesome starter for a few minutes (or even a few seconds) of math-rich play. You can have a math corner with a picture book or two, a table with some hands-on objects, and a board to hang pictures. Look up "Reggio Emilia provocations" for ideas, but don't go fancy. You'll want to remake that corner every few weeks to keep the attention fresh.

Here's how someone set up their child's mirror book table with some cute little objects, paper, pencils, etc. "Mirror book" is a chapter in "Moebius Noodles." https://happinessishereblog.com/mirror-books/ You can put any pictures with radial symmetry next to that, like Haeckel's art.

[image: Mirror Books from Moebius Noodles]

**Memory booster.** The toddler version: photograph your child at inspired play with some blocks, to spark more building. Older student version: hang up the chain rule formula after some quality time with calculus to commit it to the long-term memory. We memorize what we see multiple times in our environment.

[image: Lego 1981 ad "Beautiful"]

Answer (score 6):

Some of M. C. Escher's works illustrate many mathematical concepts.  My favorite is [Circle Limit III](https://mathstat.slu.edu/escher/index.php/File:Circle-Limit-III.jpg); it illustrates rotational symmetry, tessellations, hyperbolic geometry, limits, and infinity.  (More information about it can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Limit_III).)  Posters of M. C. Escher's works are available at the [official website](https://mcescher.com/product-category/posters/), but you might want to just download public-domain images  of them and print them out.

[image: Circle Limit III]

When I was a young child (I suppose when I was first starting to read), I saw this picture in a *Scientific American* magazine and it made me think and imagine.